# How to read specific cell value from CSV file in MQL4?

Tags: csv, mql4, metatrader4

I am trying to read just one cell value from a CSV file in MQL4, however, the online documentation doesn't cover finding single cell values and I've searched countless threads for a workaround but there are none.

My code is below,

```
  int Handle = FileOpen("/Users/rahulparmeshwar/Documents/Algo 
  /LogisticRegressionOutput.csv",FILE_READ|FILE_CSV,',');
  double Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
  Str = FileReadInteger(Handle,1);
 Alert(Str);
 FileClose(Handle);
```

The contents of the CSV file are as follows below
[image: Data]

Any help will be much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload your csv file or post its contents?

Comment: @PaulB Yes but stackoverflow doesn't let me upload files, so I've uploadede a larger picture of my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see [FileOpen Function](https://docs.mql4.com/files/fileopen)

*For security reasons, work with files is strictly controlled in the MQL4 language. Files with which file operations are conducted using MQL4 means, cannot be outside the file sandbox.*

This means you must place your csv file in the `...\MQL4\Files` folder.

Regarding your code, it is much more efficient to use an array. You can then read a specific cell value using [row][column]. Remember that arrays are zero based (your first row and column reference would be [0][0]).

```
string data[1][18]

int Handle=FileOpen("LogisticRegressionOutput.csv",FILE_CSV|FILE_SHARE_READ,",");
if(Handle<1){return(-1);}
int row=0;
ArrayResize(data,18);
while(!FileIsEnding(Handle))
{
   if(row>ArraySize(data)/18-1) {ArrayResize(data,(row+1)*18);}
   for(int i=0; i<=18-1; i++) data[row][i]=FileReadString(Handle);
   row++;
}
FileClose(Handle);
Print(data[0][0]);
```

Comment: The code above returns no value, I tried changing the string type to an integer but to no avail.

Comment: Nevermind I just had to change my PrintData array values. Thank you very much.